# ループ処理で名前の異なるリストを生み出していきたい

Tags: python

こんにちは。この度は、ループ処理でリストを生み出し、それに名前をつけるというコードが書きたくて質問しました。
具体的にはこんな感じで書きたいです。

....
任意に入力した数字をリストに格納し続けます。q１を入力すると格納は終わります。（ここまでは自力で書けています）

qを押された後に、今のリストはリスト１と名づけられます。そしてさっきと同じように入力を求められ、…q１を押すと今のリストはリスト２と名づけられます。
このようなループで任意の数nまで、リストnが作られます。q２を入力すると、リストを作るループそのものが終了します。
....

難儀なのは、ループのたびにリストの名前を変えるという点です。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「名前の付いたリスト」は[辞書型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)で表現するのが一般的な方法です。
リスト1, リスト2などの単純な連番であれば、辞書型の代わりにリストのリストを作っても良いですが、回答からは割愛します。

**サンプルコード:**

```
list = []
dict = {}
while True:
    s = input()
    if s == "q1":
        key = "リスト{}".format(len(dict) + 1)
        dict[key] = list
        list = []
    elif s == "q2":
        break
    else:
        list.append(int(s))

print(dict)
```

**出力例:** ("> "から始まる表記はキーボードによる入力を表す)

```
> 1
> 5
> q1
> 2
> 4
> 3
> q1
> q2
{'リスト1': [1, 5], 'リスト2': [2, 4, 3]}
```

Comment: なるほど、辞書！ありがとうございます。参考にします。返信遅れて申し訳ありませんでした。